# access target element in success function of jquery.load

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to access the object inside the success function of $(obj).load(); like this :

```
$('.target').load('some url',function(){
    $(this).addClass('ajaxLoaded');
});
```

to use it in $.ajaxSetup like this :

```
$.ajaxSetup({
   success : function(){
      $(this).addClass('ajaxLoaded');
   }
});
```

but can't do that $(this) return the XHR elemnt

Comment: save `$(this)` to a `var self` outside your ajax request and reference that later in your `success` callback

Comment: Why do you need to do this with `$.ajaxSetup()`? That will fire for other types of AJAX calls that aren't `.load()`, so they don't have a target element.

Answer (score 0):

Notice: $.ajaxSetup.succes will be executed before the function within load() is executed.

So, the target element is not yet known (Maybe it is known somewhere, but I can't find it).

I think the use of $.ajaxSetup is not the right tool for what you are trying to do.